# Не работает Redirect 301 в Opencart

Tags: .htaccess, opencart, seo, редирект, http-status-code-301

Нужно для SEO прописать редиректы 301, но в opencart в `.htaccess` данная строчка:

```
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

(без которой сайт не работает) ломает все ссылки и добавляет к ним `_route_`. Пробовал такой вариант, который все советуют в инете:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_route_=<Старая ссылка>$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ <Новая ссылка>? [R=301,L]
```

Но он также не работает.
Как быть, подскажите пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_route_=адрес_старой_страницы.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ваш_домен.ru/новой_страницы/? [R=301,L]
```

Так советуют. Вы же указали:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_route_=<Старая ссылка>$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ <Новая ссылка>? [R=301,L] ### Тут ошибка - где домен?
```

Ссылки:

https://moytop.com/prodvizhenie-sajtov/4-4/pravilnyj-redirekt-v-magazine-opencart

https://opencartforum.com/topic/7484-resheno-kak-pravilno-nastroit-301-redirekt/

Comment: Понятно уж, что там должна находиться ссылка, я просто указал что на этих местах должны быть адреса. Я их там указывал, и не срабатывало, указывал с доменом, все как положено